# Can Sql Server 2005 Pivot table have nText passed into it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, pivot-table

Right bit of a simple question can I input nText into a pivot table? (SQL Server 2005)

What I have is a table which records the answers to a questionnaire consisting of the following elements for example:

```
UserID   QuestionNumber   Answer 
Mic        1                Yes
Mic        2                No
Mic        3                Yes
Ste        1                Yes
Ste        2                No
Ste        3                Yes
Bob        1                Yes
Bob        2                No
Bob        3                Yes
```

With the answers being held in nText. Anyway what id like a Pivot table to do is:

```
UserID  1     2    3
Mic     Yes   No   Yes
Ste     Yes   No   Yes
Bob     Yes   No   Yes
```

I have some test code, that creates a pivot table but at the moment it just shows the number of answers in each column (code can be found below). So I just want to know is it possible to add nText to a pivot table? As when I've tried it brings up errors and someone stated on another site that it wasn't possible, so I would like to check if this is the case or not.

Just for further reference I don't have the opportunity to change the database as it's linked to other systems that I haven't created or have access too.

Heres the SQL code I have at present below:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @concatcolumns NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @count = 1
SET @concatcolumns = ''

WHILE (@count <=52)
BEGIN
      IF @COUNT > 1 AND @COUNT <=52
            SET @concatcolumns = (@concatcolumns + ' + ')
      SET @concatcolumns = (@concatcolumns + 'CAST ([' +  CAST(@count AS NVARCHAR) + '] AS NVARCHAR)')
      SET @count = (@count+1)
END

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @count = 1
SET @columns = ''
WHILE (@count <=52)
BEGIN
      IF @COUNT > 1 AND @COUNT <=52
            SET @columns = (@columns + ',')
      SET @columns = (@columns + '[' +  CAST(@count AS NVARCHAR) + '] ')
      SET @count = (@count+1)
END

SET @query = '
SELECT UserID,
' + @concatcolumns + '    
FROM(   
            SELECT
                      UserID,
                      QuestionNumber AS qNum
                      from QuestionnaireAnswers
                      where QuestionnaireID = 7
      ) AS t

      PIVOT
      (
      COUNT (qNum)
      FOR qNum IN (' + @columns + ')
      ) AS PivotTable'
select @query
exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert it to an `nvarchar(MAX)` - that will work just fine. FYI, you shouldn't really be using `ntext` under 2005+ - it's deprecated. Hope that helps.

Comment: I would'nt normally but this is a bit of a legacy database that I haven't built (was my boss). I'll get around to bringing it up to date at some point but really don't have the time at the moment lol

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a while loop making column names, use the function `COALESCE`. And also you can use the function `QuoteName` to make the column name in square brackets.